# How to enumerate over selected elements from an iterable keeping original indices?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, enumerate

I run into the case of **using an enumerator on *selected* elements form an iterable** (i.e. a *sequence* or an *iterator* or similar) and want that the ***original* indices were being returned** instead of the default `count`, starting by `0` and going up to `len(iterable) - 1`.

A very naive approach would be the declaration of **a new *generator object*** called `_enumerate()`

```
>>> def _enumerate(iterable, offset = 0, step = 1):
    index = offset
    for element in iterable:
        yield index, element
        index += step
```

... a new **list object `months`**.

```
>>> months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
              "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
```

Using Pythons **build-in `enumerate` function** would yield this **output** for a `[5::2]` slice:

```
>>> for index, element in enumerate(months[5::2]):
    print(index, element)


    0 June
    1 August
    2 October
    3 December
```

The ***expected output* of our own enumerator** `_enumerate` again for a `[5::2]` slice:

```
>>> for index, element in _enumerate(months[5::2], offset = 5, step = 2):
    print(index, element)


    5 June
    7 August
    9 October
    11 December
```

*Do you know any better, more pythonic and more readable solutions?* :)

Comment: Your answer is pythonic and readable enough.

Comment: How about `i*step+offset`? Should also give you the desired indices...

Comment: You could avoid repeating yourself by having `_enumerate` do the slicing as well (ie call it as `_enumerate(month, offset=5, step=2`), but that would require `months` to be a list in order to be efficient.

Comment: @swenzel: Where do you  insert `index * step + offset`?

Comment: @skyking: Yes. Thanks, thats a good point :)

Comment: Wherever you need your "real" index. E.g. `print(index*2+5, element)` with the normal enumerate will also give you "5 June", "7 August"... Or you could put `index = index*step+offset` as first line in your loop.

Comment: @swenzel: Oh yeah :) Yes I am silly. Thats a nice solution! Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here my comment as an answer ;)

```
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
          "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

offset = 5
step = 2
for index, element in enumerate(months[offset::step]):

    # recalculate original index
    index = offset + index*step

    # actually repetition of the month is trivial,
    # but I put it just to show that the index is right
    print(index, element, months[index])
```

Prints:

```
5 June June
7 August August
9 October October
11 December December
```

Comment: Nice solution. Very readable and easy to understand in my opinion :) Thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) + `enumerate()`, to select elements with original indices:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> for i, month in islice(enumerate(calendar.month_abbr), 6, None, 2):
...     print(i, month)
... 
6 Jun
8 Aug
10 Oct
12 Dec
```

It does not duplicate the slice information and uses existing functions with familiar behavior.

Or if you know that the original iterable is small; you could call `list()`:

```
>>> list(enumerate(calendar.month_abbr))[6::2]
[(6, 'Jun'), (8, 'Aug'), (10, 'Oct'), (12, 'Dec')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like using `range(len(...`, but maybe it's okay here.

```
>>> months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
...           "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
>>> print(*('{:>2} {}'.format(i, months[i]) for i in range(len(months))[5::2]), sep='\n')
 5 June
 7 August
 9 October
11 December
```

To expand out of the one-liner:

```
offset = 5
step = 2
r = range(len(months))

for i in r[offset::step]:
    print('{:>2} {}'.format(i, months[i]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) But it's the question if your solution is more readable than a generator for instance ...

Comment: It would probably be more readable with some assignments and a normal loop instead of being rolled into a one-liner, but I think the basic concept is okay.

Comment: Yes, you're right :) You could add the "normal loop" (loop and print statement separated) to your answer if you feel like it :D

Comment: @elegent - Good idea; added.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools as it

months = [
    "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
]

print list(
    it.islice(it.izip(it.count(1), months), 5, len(months), 2)
)
```

To answer the further questions in comment:

- Normal slice won't work on `itertools.izip`, since it does not support the `__getitem__` method.
- Yes, `itertools.izip` was removed from Python 3, and the regular builtin `zip` works with the same generator semantics.

Comment: Thanks :) But why should we use `islice` form `itertools` instead of a "normal" slice? And as far as I know `izip` is `zip` in Python 3.x. You cloud add this information to your answer.